# I can not passing variable to Main method (Cucumber)

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, methods, parameter-passing

I had tried to create method and call it from another file to the main class but It won't work the error message said "java.lang.NullPointerException"

Main.class

```
Keywords kw = new Keywords();

@When("^gmailDD$") 
     public void gmailDD() throws Throwable{
     WebDriverWait wait5s = new WebDriverWait(driver, 5);
     String regis = "/html/body/div[2]/div[1]/div[5]/ul[1]/li[3]/a";
     String dd = "/html/body/div[1]/div/footer/div/div/div[1]";
     String empty = "/html/body/div[1]/div/footer";


     kw.clickbyxpath(regis);


     String handle= driver.getWindowHandle();
     System.out.println(handle);       
        // Store and Print the name of all the windows open               
        Set handles = driver.getWindowHandles();
        System.out.println("Log window id: "+handles);
        driver.switchTo().window("6442450949");

     kw.clickbyxpath(empty);   
     kw.clickbyxpath(dd);

}`
```

Method.class

```
WebDriver saddriver;

public void clickbyxpath (String xpathvalue) throws InterruptedException, IOException 
    {   
            WebDriverWait sad   =   new WebDriverWait(saddriver, 10); 

              //To wait for element visible
            System.out.println(xpathvalue);
            String x = xpathvalue;
            sad.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath(x)));

            wowdriver.findElement(By.xpath(x)).click();                 
    }
```

I had tried to do the same coding in the same file, It has no problem but when I move Method.class to the new file, error message said "java.lang.NullPointerException"  but I can get "xpathvalue" value.

Comment: can you please post your error stack trace for more details. might be it will not able to found your window.

Comment: the error message showing at "kw.clickbyxpath(regis);" in Main.class file and the second error showing at "WebDriverWait sad   =   new WebDriverWait(saddriver, 10); " in Method.class file

Comment: I had read these error log and It's about WebDriver and WebDriverWait.

Comment: this happen because it will not find your driver instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This Error occur because of it will not able to find your driver instance.

refer below code snippet. this is not cucumber example but you can get idea by this.

**Method.class**

```
package testing.framework;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

public class Method {

    public WebDriver driver;
    WebElement _clickForSearch;
    public Method(WebDriver driver) {
        this.driver = driver;
    }
    public Method clickByXpath(String xpathValues) {
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
        _clickForSearch = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath(xpathValues)));
        _clickForSearch.click();    
        return this;
    }


}
```

**Testing.class**

```
package testing.framework;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class Testing {
    public static WebDriver driver;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        getWebDriver();
        String xpathValues= "//div[@class='FPdoLc VlcLAe']//input[@name='btnK']";
        Method m1 = new Method(driver);
        m1.clickByXpath(xpathValues);

    }

    public static void getWebDriver() {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "Your chrome driver path");
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("https://www.google.com");
    }

}
```

You need to pass your driver instance to another.

Answer (score 1):

So I would suggest you take the webdriver wait out of your method and instantiate it when instantiating your webdriver. I would then create methods like so:

**Driver class**

```
private final String USER_DIRECTORY = System.getProperty("user.dir");
private final int GLOBAL_TIMEOUT = 30;
private WebDriver webDriver;
private WebDriverWait webDriverWait;


public Driver(String browserName) {
    this.browserName = browserName;
    System.out.println(browserName);
    switch (this.browserName.toUpperCase()) {

        case "CHROME":
            initializeChromeDriver();
            break;
    }
}
private void initializeChromeDriver() {
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", USER_DIRECTORY.concat("\\drivers\\chromedriver.exe"));
    webDriver = new ChromeDriver();
    webDriver.manage().window().maximize();
    webDriverWait = new WebDriverWait(webDriver, GLOBAL_TIMEOUT);
}
```

*Click method*

```
   public void buttonClickByXpath(String xpath) {
    try {
        WaitForPreseneOfElement(xpath);
        webDriver.findElement(By.xpath(xpath)).click();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        takeScreenshot();
        AllureLog("Failed to click on the button object. Please check your xpath. | xpath used = " + xpath + "");
        Assert.fail();

    }
}
```

**Test Class**
Import your driver class

```
import Base.Driver;
```

Then you would need declair your driver class like so:

```
Driver driver;
```

Now you will have access to your method using

```
driver.buttonClickByXpath(//YourXpathHere)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is "Method m1 = new Method(driver);" keyword, 
I had coded this line outside the main method. 
thank you very much, Sir